# Is there a way to have an "automatic" join in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, join, relational-database

I mean the following: 
I have 2 parent tables :

table1
id PRIMARY KEY
name TEXT

table2
id PRIMARY KEY
...

and a child table, used fo n-n Relations : 
table_child 
id PRIMARY KEY
id_1 INT
id_2 INT

where id_1 and id_2 in table_child refer to the column id in table1 and table2.

Now : i often perform request, with a join between table_1 and table_child ON table1.id = table_child.id1, only because i need the value of the column table1.name. 
I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid these joins, and declare somehow a "pseudo" column name in table_child, which would not be a real column, but a link to the corresponding column in table_1, so that :
* I can acces the value through table_child.name
* But it is always synchronized with the value table1.name

I hope my explanation was understandable...

Comment: This is what `VIEW`s were made for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment above, the answer you're really looking for is something like:

```
CREATE VIEW
    table1_child_view AS
SELECT
    table1.name,
    table1_child.*
FROM
    table1_child
INNER JOIN
    table1 ON
        table1.id = table1_child.id_1
```

Then you can run your queries on the new view, such as:

```
SELECT name FROM table1_child_view WHERE ...
```

Comment: ok, great. But a view is read-only isn't it ? To be able to update, i have to use RULE instead of VIEW, right ?

Comment: Why are views being read-only a problem ?  Views are read-only but hand-written RA xpressions are not ?

Comment: @nicoroy: That or an instead of trigger, yes. That being said, simpler views are actually editable in 9.3: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.3#Updatable_Views

Comment: sorry, my remark was not clear. I mean, i want to be able to do something like UPDATE table1_child_view SET name = 'blabla'. As well, i want to use this "view" embedded in more complex request, in particular to JOIN it with another table ,e.g., SELECT * FROM table_child_view AS t1 INNER JOIN some_table AS t2 WHERE t1.name = ... Is it possible with VIEWs ?